# Log effective URL for Spring Boot Liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7. When I run a unit test, it insists on creating the Liquibase change log table either twice for what *should* be an H2 in memory database.

I'd like to have Liquibase log the *actual* JDBC URL being used. I know what the properties say, but I have an application.properties, an application-h2.properties, and sometimes Spring wants to use an in memory database even though a different in memory database is used.

Is there some property like `spring.liquibase.show-effective-jdbc-url=true`?

I'd also be interested in how to log this for regular JPA access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a flag, but the effective URL is logged at FINE level. There should be a message like `Connected to USER@URL` where the value for url is returned from the driver itself, not just what you gave it.

Comment: IMHO, I wish they would have an option to log this without logging every minute detail of the process. I'm not a fan of keeping things like that a secret or burried in too many details. But thanks nonetheless.

Comment: You can always open an issue at https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues with the suggestion and we can talk about adding it